# How to make perl to keep perform action until the match is found

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and trying to write a code to keep executing an action until the match is found and else give an error.

I am trying to execute a command `ps -ef` and check if it has got any process running in the name of "box", if there is no process named "box" found, I want to repeat `ps -ef` command execution until it gets the "box" process and then proceed to next action.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open (FH, "ps -ef |") or die "Cannot run the command:$!\n";

$line = "box";

while (<FH>) {
    if (/$line/i)  { next; }
    else { 
        print ("ps -ef |") or die "Cannot run the command:$!\n");        
    }
}
close (FH);
```

Comment: Going forward, please [edit] your question instead of heaping comments.

Comment: Wrap all of the code in another while loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an infinite loop and an exit-condition. Your condition is that the `ps -ef` command contains the word *box*. There is no need to `open` a pipe to that command explicitly, you can just run it as a system call with the [`qx` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) (same as backticks).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ps;
PS: while (1) {
    $ps = qx/ps -ef/;
    last PS if $ps =~ m/box/i;
    print '.'; # do something in every run
}

print $ps;
```

As this has come up in the comments as well as in in AdrianHHH's answer: it might make sense to `sleep` after every run to make sure [you don't hog the CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_hog). Depending on the nature of the process you are looking for, either the [`sleep` builtin](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) or `usleep` from [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) might be appropriate. The latter let's your program rest for milliseconds, while the builtin only works with full seconds. These might be too long if the target *box* process is very quick.

---

**Explanation of your code:**
Note that you have some issues in your implementation. I'll explain what your code does. This is taken from the question, comments are mine.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl -w
>
> # open a filehandle to the ps command
> open (FH, "ps -ef |") or die "Cannot run the command:$!\n";
>
> $line = "box";
>
> # read the output of one run line by line, for each line execute
> # the block
> while (<FH>) {
>     # if there is 'box' case-insensitive, skip the line
>     if (/$line/i)  { next; }
>     else { 
>         # else output (not run!) the command
>         print ("ps -ef |") or die "Cannot run the command:$!\n");        
>     }
> }
> close (FH);
> ```

After it went through all the lines of the output of your command once it will stop.

Comment: Hi All..Thanks for your replies. Adiran, Hope I have got it working using the code given by you although I am still trying to understand better how it loops until the condition is met..Many Many Thanks

Comment: Maybe also add a `sleep` to avoid hogging the CPU.

Comment: @tripleee yes, would be useful, but it depends on the nature of the process OP is looking for. If it's a long-running thing the `sleep` is useful. If it's something that will just be there and gone, it might make it miss the thing. I've added that to the answer. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`pgrep(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) instead of `ps` because it lets you do a more granular search. With `ps -ef`, you potentially have to deal with cases like:

```
boxford  6254  6211  0 08:23 pts/1  00:00:00 /home/boxford/box --bounding-box=123
```

It's hard to tell if you're matching a process being run by a user with `box` in their username, a process that has `box` somewhere in its path, a process named `box`, or a process with `box` somewhere in its argument list.

`pgrep`, on the other hand, lets you match against just the process name or the full path, a specific user or users, and more. The following prints a message when a process named `box` appears (this looks for an exact match, so it will not match processes named `dropbox`, for example):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote);

sub is_running {
    my ($proc) = @_;

    my $cmd = 'pgrep -x ' . shell_quote($proc) . ' >/dev/null 2>&1';
    system($cmd);

    if ($? == -1) {
        die "failed to execute pgrep: $!";
    }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        die "pgrep died with signal ", $? & 127;
    }
    else {
        my $status = $? >> 8;
        die "pgrep exited with error: exit status $status" if $status > 1;

        return $status == 0;
    }
}

my $proc = 'box';

until ( is_running($proc) ) {
    sleep 1;
}

say "Process '$proc' is running";
```

Note that `pgrep` doesn't have a case-insensitive flag, probably because process names in *nix are almost always lowercase. If you really need to do a case-insensitive match, you can pass `[Bb][Oo][Xx]` to the `is_running` function.

Comment: +1  An alternative to _pgrep_ would be to use [standard _ps_ formatting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html#tag_20_96_10) to restrict the output to minimally necessary fields.  E.g., `ps -eo comm`

Answer (score 0):

The `ps` command outputs the *current* list of processes, then it completes. The code in the question reads that output. Suppose that the first `ps` command that is executed does not contain the wanted line, then there is nothing in the code in the question to run the `ps` command again.

The `next` statement in the question makes the script move on to the next line in the output from `ps`, not to rerun the command. The `else print ...` after the `next` will probably be executed for the first line of the output from `ps`. The outcome is that the `print` is run for each line in the `ps` output that does not have the wanted text and that the `next` command has no significant effect. In the code `print ... or die "..."` the `or die "..."` part is not very useful, the print is unlikely to fail and even if it did the `die` message would be wrong.

Perhaps you should write some code in the following style. Here the `ps` is run repeatedly until the wanted text is found. Note the `sleep` call, without that the script will keep running without pause, possibly preventing real work or at least slowing it down.

```
# This code is not tested.
use strict;
use warnings;
my $found_wanted_line = 0; # Boolean, set to false
my $line = "box";
while ( ! $found_wanted_line ) {
    open (my $FH, "ps -ef |") or die "Cannot run the command:$!\n";
    while (<$FH>) {
        if (/$line/i) {
            $found_wanted_line = 1; # Boolean, set to true
            last;
        }
    }
    close ($FH);

    if ( ! $found_wanted_line )
        sleep 2; # Pause for 2 seconds, to prevent this script hogging the CPU.
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the `sleep`, though it might miss the run of the _box_ program if you wait for two seconds. You also have a syntax error. You cannot declare a bareword filehandle with `my`. Use a lexical `$fh` instead. And you can move the `my $line` outside the outer loop, no need to redeclare it every time as it never changes.

Comment: @simbabque good point, it might miss a short running program. The questioner will have to consider that if they use code based on this answer.

Comment: @simbabque ..Thanks Much for your suggestion. I tried the similar code earlier but it does not loop until the condition is met. Also, I would like to get the ps -ef command output to be added in the file handle for the next set of actions in the script

Comment: @user have you realized you are writing to mee on Adrian's answer and to him on mine? This is really confusing. I don't understand which answer you are referring to. As for the comment, I have tested my code (the `while (1)` loop). It works very nicely, though not with _box_, because my system has programs running all the time that have the string _box_ in their name. I used _firefox_ to try it, which is not my default browser. Worked like a charm. If you want the output, put it in a variable before you run the match. I've updated [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31981171/1331451).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion..its my mistake read it incorrect. Many Thanks for your kind suggestions and help.